# Editing compiled kernel module for more compatibility

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

I want to edit compiled kernel module file (`module.ko`) to insert something like `"MODULE_INFO(vermagic, "3.10.9-blabla");"` because this module file does not load with `insmod` and i get the error `"failed (Exec format error)"`, the module was made for `2.6.35-smp` version, I'm new to linux.

Comment: Hi,

Every kernel module is built for a very specific kernel version. This ensure stability.

What you actually need is to build your module against the 3.10.0-blabla kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* edit a compiled module directly.
Whatever change you need to do, you have to edit the source file and then compile it again.

From version 2.6.35 to 3.10 quite a lot of things changed; most likely the module is not compatible at all and it will not work. So, even if you can change the `vermagic` in the binary file it will not work because it's incompatible.

In your case, as Hector said, you have to recompile the module against a different Linux version. This process will also highlight all the incompatibilities that you should fix too.

If you do not have the sources because it is not an open source module: complain with the vendor :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you will not be able to **edit** your compiled module now, build your kernel with `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is not set` from next time, for driver development. It will enable you to make any number of incremental changes to your driver and load it against the newly built kernel with `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is not set`.

`CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` is a notion thought up to make people's lives easier. If your kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y`, it enables you
to only be able to load modules that were compiled specifically for
that kernel version. Whereas, if your kernel is built with `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is not set`, it will enable your `driver` to load on any kernel where `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is not set`. You can modify this field in the `.config` file of your `linux-kernel` directory.